# JUnit exception test case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

i am trying to write junit test case expecting the NullPointer Exception.
like this

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
        public void testException() throws CustomiseException {
            CustomBean expected= new CustomBean();
```

//below line will throw null pointer exception , that i want to test with junit

```
        when(repo.isValid().thenReturn(expected);       

        }
```

but when running Junit it is getting failed with below error:
it is throwing exception at the same line which i want to test, can anyone help me with this ?
[image]

Comment: The error message simply means that the code you wanted to test did not throw the `NullPointerException` that you expected. Now it's your job to find out why.

Comment: @Jesper i am not able to find

Comment: I can't help you any further because I don't know what the code you are testing looks like (you didn't include that), what your test code looks like (you only included part of that) and why you expect it to throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: the line:
 when(repo.isValid().thenReturn(expected);    
seems is missing a closed bracket